# Как сделать переключение между пунктами меню

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть блок сверху окна со стилем `z-index:1;`.  В нем 4 параграфа (`<p>`):

```
<p class="up1">Главная</p>
<p class="up1">Расписание</p>
<p class="up1">Записи</p>
<p class="up1">Помощь></p>
```

Также заготовлено 4 блока, первый со стилем `display:block;`, остальные 3 со стилем `display:none;` Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на текст "Расписание", появлялся второй блок, а первый пропадал, и так далее. Я думаю это можно сделать при помощи изменения стиля display у первого и второго блоков, либо при помощи js

Answer (score 1):

Кратко

```js
const ps = [...document.querySelectorAll('p')]
for (let i = 0; i < ps.length; ++i) {
  const e = ps[i]
  e.addEventListener('click', () => {
    e.classList.remove('show')
    ps[i === ps.length - 1 ? 0 : i + 1].classList.add('show')
  })
}
```

```css
p {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

p.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p class="show">Главная</p>
<p>Расписание</p>
<p>Записи</p>
<p>Помощь</p>
```

Comment: К сожалению, это не работает

Comment: @pythoner По всей видимости, оно и не будет работать как задумано, так как вопрос совершенно не ясен. И ответ лишь указывает на возможный вариант переключения видимости элементов, который можно взять за основу.